# Ruby on rails select tags from fixed lists(rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I have some models, for example, Post, User. Is it possible to use tags only from fixed lists of tags for model Post and model User?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a validation before saving your tags, checking that tags are included in an array (that could be stored in database, a constant, a file..).
In the view part, that depends on what are you using, but assuming you are using a jquery plugin, check for one that accepts an array of possible tags and pass it yours. This one for example (check the typeahead part): https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/